# Program to Reverse Whole Array

Tags: c

can some please explain me the algorthem for this...

i understnad it will reading elements... and then have few problems :( would some one please explain this a detailed manner! plesae!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
  int array[100], n, c, t, end;


 printf("Enter How mnay Number of elements you want in array:");
  scanf("%d",&n);                                                      
  end = n - 1;              
 printf("Enter %d elements:",n);
  for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    scanf("%d", &array[c]);  
  }

  for (c = 0; c < n/2; c++) {  
    t          = array[c];
    array[c]   = array[end];
    array[end] = t;
    end--;
  }

  printf("Reversed array elements are:\n");

  for (c = 0; c < n; c++) {
    printf("%d\n", array[c]);
  }
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: It swaps the first element & last element and works towards the middle of the array.

Comment: This question lacks specifics on what part of this relatively straightforward code you do not understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could step it through a debugger. Basically, it first asks for an array of numbers, and then loops from the first element, to the middle one swapping the element before the middle, with the corresponding element after the middle.

An example:

```
1 2 3 4

4 2 3 1

4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 key things:

1. Look at how `c` and `end` change with each iteration of the middle loop
2. Walk through the body of that loop for 1 iteration to see how it works.